# Display tooltip over line breaks in text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using tooltips in bootstrap3.

If you hover over the gap between the lines in the 'Position' column in the table example, the tool tip will disappear.  Notice that the mouse pointer changes from arrow to 'text'.

[image: break in text]

How do I get it so that the tooltip is always displayed when hovering over the cell.

Note that I tried to move the tooltip to the parent `td`, but this is no good because when hovering it brings in a div which breaks the table formatting.

I believe it should be possible to solve this using CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthewhegarty/w5Lyro9j/22/)

Comment: can you div tag instead of span tag

Comment: Would it be acceptable if any space inside the cell triggers it? Even the whitespace that's far to the right? Because if that's acceptable, you can either put the tooltip on the td tag itself or replace span with a div. I think the issue is with how spans behave.

Comment: thanks - I cannot put the tooltip on the td tag because it breaks the formatting.  Using a div does solve the issue, but the HTML code is generated from a plugin which I'd rather not change.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers which got me to the solution.

Either using `div` (not `span`) solves the issue, or declaring the following css:

```css
[data-toggle="tooltip"]{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this happen because the td have a padding of 8 px-  to fix it try that:

```
[data-toggle="tooltip"]{
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding:8px;
}

.table>tbody>tr>td{
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I need to have the padding on the table for formatting reasons, but the `display: block` property solves the issue.